# Как после consumer rebalance процесса, сбросить offset, что бы Consumer мог прочитать топик сначала?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

Есть ситуация, когда **Consumer1** читает сообщения из кафка топика. При подключении второго **Consumer2** с таким же **groupId**, происходит перераспределение партиций, можно ли как то сбросить **offset**, что бы после процесса перераспределения, оба **Consumer'а** читали топик с начала?

Мне нужно что бы во время процесса перерапределения партиций, выполнялась определенная логика, в том числе что бы после каждого перераспределения партиций сбрасывалось значение **offset**, что бы после перераспределения информация равномерно распределилась между потребителями. Я нашел, что процесс ре-балансировки партиций модно отследить реализовав интерфейс **ConsumerRebalanceListener**

```
@Service
public class KafkaRebalanceListenerHandler implements ConsumerRebalanceListener {

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {

    }
}
```

И далее указать переопределенный **KafkaRebalanceListenerHandler** при настройке **KafkaConsumer**

```
    @Bean
    @RefreshScope
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> listenerFactory() {
        final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setErrorHandler(kafkaListenerErrorHandler);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerRebalanceListener(kafkaRebalanceListenerHandler);
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
```

с этим вроде тоже разобрался. Остается неясность, как привязавшись к перераспределению партиций, застравить вычитывать топик заново.

Comment: Это похоже на проблему [молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/218971). Вручную можно оффсеты сбросить, но я так понимаю вы хотите автоматически? Зачем вам это нужно?

Comment: @RomanKonoval
У меня есть сервис, который будет считывать кафка топик и сохранять определенную информацию. Когда сервис задеплоен возможна ситуация увеличения экземпляров сервиса до двух. Поднимется второй экземпляр этого сервиса с той же **groupId**.В этот момент произойдет перебалансировка. Как привязаться к ней я нашел нужно реализовать интерфейс **ConsumerRebalanceListener**,  и как я понимаю, в этих переопределенных методах и нужно как-то сбросить значение **offset**, что бы после переназначения партиций два **consumer'a** вычитали топик примерно в равной степени.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, добавил описание, надеюсь на чуть полее подробное объяснение в том числе как добавить, то что указали вы в настройку **Consumer**

Comment: _Что_ вы хотите понятно, но вот _зачем_ вам делать reset и таким образом еще раз обрабатывать уже полученные сообщения - это не ясно. Какую задачу вы с помощью reset пробуете решить?

Comment: @RomanKonoval, поднятие второго экземпляра прилоожения означает то, что первый не справил с пост-обработкой такого количества сообщений, и после поднятия второго экземпляра, они должны вычитать топик и поделить последующую нагрузку примерно поровну

Comment: Если у вас в партициях данных делятся примерно равномерно (и каждое сообщение приносит с собой приблизительно одинаковое количество работы), то вы это и получите без переустановки офсетов. Если же данные делятся неравномерно, то переустановка не поможет. Переустановка офсетов влияет исключительно на то, что обработчики заново будут обрабатывать уже обработанные сообщения. Так что, если мотивация - увеличить производительность путем деления работы, то переустановка не имеет смысла, а только будет тормозить процесс.

Comment: @drugzverya Roman Konoval совершенно верно говорит о том, что сброс offset'ов не перераспределит нагрузку, а наоборот ее увеличит (старые сообщения будут прочитаны еще раз). Чтобы увеличить производительность, достаточно создать кол-во consumer'ов, равное кол-ву partition'ов в вашем топике (без сброса оффсетов).

Comment: @aleshka-batman, у меня нагрузка происходит не от самих кафка сообщений, а от действий по их обработке. и мне логично, если не справляется один экземпляр сервиса не справляется, поднять второй, прочитать топик заново, разделив сообщения между двумя сервисами и обработать их еще раз, те сообщения которые были обработаны пропустятся, обработаются те, до которых первый экземпляр не  дошел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идее достаточно реализовать `ConsumerSeekAware` в вашем listener-e, а именно метод `onPartitionsAssigned`, чтоб он сбрасывал offset-ы на начало, когда партиция назначается данному **Consumer**-у:

```
public class KafkaMessageListener implements ConsumerSeekAware {
    @KafkaListener(topics = "my.topic")
    public void listen(byte[] payload) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void registerSeekCallback(ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
        assignments.forEach((t, o) -> callback.seekToBeginning(t.topic(), t.partition()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onIdleContainer(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
    }
}
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/a/47778893/2231972